# Property of multiplication of ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, ideal-class-group

Let $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$ be two coprime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ such that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} = (n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does $\mathfrak{a}^m = (u)$ imply $\mathfrak{b}^m = (u)$, $u\in \mathbb Z$? I get that the order of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $ \mathfrak{b}$ must be the same since they are inverses in the ideal class group but I'm not sure why $\mathfrak{a}^m = \mathfrak{b}^m$.

Comment: What is $(u)$ exactly?

Comment: The ideal generated by some $u \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Haven't solve the problem yet, but an observation: prime numbers $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ can only decompose into a product of prime ideals in three ways: $\mathfrak p \mathfrak p', \mathfrak p^2$, or just $p$.  It follows that if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal such that $\mathfrak a^m = (u)$ for some $u$, then necessarily $m = 2$, and $\mathfrak a$ is equal to a product $\mathfrak p_1 \cdots \mathfrak p_t k$, where $k$ is an integer, and $\mathfrak p_i$ are not necessarily distinct prime ideals such that $\mathfrak p_i^2 = (p_i)$ for some rational prime number $p_i$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathfrak a^m = \mathfrak b^m$ as fractional ideals?  The fractional ideals form a free abelian group, so $\mathfrak a^m = \mathfrak b^m$ is equivalent to $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak b$.

Comment: Ok, I thought a bit more about it and if $\mathfrak{b} = (k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ it is sufficient to show we can write $k$ in terms of $u$. So we use the relation $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} = (n)$, but I can't seem to write down anything concrete.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is true.  Hopefully I haven't misunderstood your question.  Consider $d = -1$.  Let $\mathfrak p = (1+i)$, so $\mathfrak p^2 = (2)$.  Let $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak p$, and $\mathfrak b = \mathfrak p^3$.  Then $\mathfrak a \mathfrak b = \mathfrak p^4 = (4)$ is the ideal generated by an integral, and also $\mathfrak a^2 = (2)$ is the ideal generated by an integral.  But $\mathfrak a^2 \neq \mathfrak b^2$.

Comment: There might be missing information from my question. The original question is exercise 6.4.1 in Murdy and Esmonde's book *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory*.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's required that $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are co-prime.